# Can I get memory usage of processes running on the monitored server by newrelic REST API

Tags: newrelic

According to the [New Relic documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/new-relic-infrastructure/get-started/introduction-new-relic-infrastructure), the Server Monitoring agent can report Top 20 processes that are using significant memory or I/O, and I can view the memory usage of the processes on the New Relic portal page.

However, I do not see how to get these metrics using the New Relic REST API (I can get the CPU usage of processes via the REST API). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple way to do this with the New Relic API at the moment. You may wish to SSH into your box and execute a top command or create a cron job to execute a top command and then send the information to you on a regular schedule either in a file you host or via email etc……. You can always contact New Relic directly for more information https://support.newrelic.com